# Calculate current class height and replace with another class in same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created an ajax pagination for my wordpress blog theme, and it's working perfectly, except the fact that when a user clicks on next page link (pagination links) the whole posts area is removed while loading next page content, I want same container dimensions to be maintained while loading new content and show a spinner or loader in the middle of this container

here is the code

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.pagination a', function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

page = find_page_number( $(this).clone() );

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'ajax_pagination',
        query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
        page: page
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.mg-posts-wrapper').find( 'article' ).remove();
        $('.mg-posts-wrapper .pagination').remove();
        $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.mg-posts-wrapper').append( '<div class="page-content" id="loader">Loading New Posts...</div>' );
    },
    success: function( html ) {
        $('.mg-posts-wrapper #loader').remove();
        $('.mg-posts-wrapper').append( html );
    }
})
})
```

as you see, this is the output before sending success result. the current content is removed and replaced with this while loading content

```
<div class="page-content" id="loader">Loading New Posts...</div>
```

now instead of this I want to create a loader that grabs container height and apply it to itself or if there is another way I'm open to suggestions, I just want a way to make the user experience better and make the transition between pages easier.

Answer (score 0):

something can go well? (CSS3 + jQuery)

```js
var updatePost = function(){
  this.e = false;
  
  this.find = function(selector){
    this.e = $(selector);
    return this;
  };
  
  this.fix = function(){ // function to update the height
    this.e.height(this.e.find('.int').height());
    return this;
  };
  
  this.write = function(html){
    this.e.find('.int').html(html);
    return this;
  }
};

// example:
var test = new updatePost().find('.post').write('Food<br/><br/>google!<br/><br/><br/>bar!!').fix();
setTimeout(function(){
  test.write('loading..');
  setTimeout(function(){
    test.write('Food!<br/><br/><br/>').fix();
  },2500);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.post {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  background: blue;
}

.post .int {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post">
  <div class="int">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**
here is an example of how to apply the function.

```
var updatePost = function() {
    this.e = false;

    this.find = function(selector) {
        this.e = $(selector);
        return this;
    };

    this.fix = function() { // function to update the height
        this.e.height(this.e.find('.int').height());
        return this;
    };

    this.write = function(html) {
        this.e.find('.int').html(html);
        return this;
    }
};


$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    page = find_page_number($(this).clone());

    var updatePage = new updatePost(); // load function
    updatePage.find('.mg-posts-wrapper'); // find element
    if ($('.mg-posts-wrapper .int').length == 0) $('.mg-posts-wrapper').wrapInner("<div class='int'></div>"); // add div INT

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_pagination',
            query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
            page: page
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.mg-posts-wrapper').find('article').remove();
            $('.mg-posts-wrapper .pagination').remove();
            $(document).scrollTop();
            updatePage.fix(); // fix height page
            updatePage.write('<div class="page-content" id="loader">Loading New Posts...</div>');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            updatePage.write(html);
            updatePage.fix(); // update height!
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: How exactly can I implement this to the code I'm using, also I see it's not mainting height while loading, it's just transitioning

Comment: Thank you, but somehow this doesn't work as intended, it doesn't scroll to top, and the height of the second page is not correct, meaning it's lower than first page keeping a part of it cut, probably defining min-height will fix this?

Comment: also, is there a way to make it scroll to top once a classes are clicked, not after page load